# Deleting a tag from lots of images at once in Aperture?

Tags: macos, images, processing, tags, aperture

Aperture makes it easy to tag lost of pictures at once by just selecting all the images, and the dragging and dropping tags from the tags pallet onto the selected images. But when you need to do the reverse, I can't find a way other than editing each image individually.

Is there a way I could select multiple images at once and strip a tag out of all of them?

Thanks,

Bart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bart,
Last time I added a URL in my post and my points were taken away, down to 1, so I am not going to put the URL here, but you can google for:

```
removing keywords from multiple images site: blogs.oreilly.com
```

To paraphrase the steps:

1. Select all pictures with tags (keywords) you want to remove
2. Menu: Window > Show Control Bar
3. Menu: Window > Show Keywords Control. The keywords control bar will appear at the bottom
4. Click inside the "Add keyword" text box and type your keyword, then hit Shift+Enter

That should do it. By the way, I am fan of the NosillaCast and especially like your segment with Allison. Keep up the good works.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm!

FAR from what I'd call intuitive - but hey, it works!

Thanks again, and thanks for your kind words about the NosillaCast. Rest assured, myself and Allison have more fun making it than anyone could possibly have listening to it :)